# Jquery add class and keep when page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies, local-storage

I have a simple navigation menu. Home link has a dropdown active class. I need to do this:
When user press for example Article link, jquery has to remove dropdown active class from Home and set this class to selected link. I know that I can use removeClass and addClass , but I need to keep selected link class when page is reload. I heard about cookies and localstorage to set class, but I don't know how. Can someone help me?

```
   <ul>
    <li class="dropdown active"><a>Home</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a>Articles</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a>About</a></li>
   </ul>
```

Comment: Please provide your `href` link according to menu name

Comment: I think that a simple solution would be set the class from the server side. What is the server side language you are using? Are you using a framework? If so, you can use a template engine to achieve this and avoid the coupling between presentation and the "logic".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You can use with jquery in this way:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        if($(".dropdown  a").attr("href")==window.location.href){
            $(".dropdown").attr("class","dropdown active");
        }
       else{
          $(".dropdown").attr("class","dropdown");
         }
    });
```

Comment: When I open website, all links gets dropdown active class and when I click on other link, dropdown active class resets. MY href something like this : http://localhost/thoughts/quotes , http://localhost/interesting/articles and so on :)

Comment: Then add `$(".dropdown").attr("class","dropdown");` this code into else bolck.

Comment: still doesn't work. All links gets dropdown active class, and when I click on the link, all li classes changes to dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Just check once for any err,this should resolve your issue.

```
   <ul class="nav">
    <li class="dropdown active"><a>Home</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a>Articles</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a>About</a></li>
   </ul>

$('.nav li').click(function(){
      $('.navt li').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

or using cookie(ideally not very good option)

**set_page.php**

> setcookie('nav', 'put-the-li-classname-here', time(),'/');

**receive_page.php**

> $getnav = $_COOKIE['nav'];

**js**

> var variable1 = // get the php val here;
>
> ```
> $(document).ready(function(){
>      $('.navt li').removeClass('active');
>        $('.'+variable1).addClass('active');
> ```
>
> });

Comment: clicked link when page reload must keep dropdown active class, so this code isn't correct I think. :)

Comment: I'm using CI framework. It won't be an easy way to adobt this code. If cookie isn't good way to store, so what is the best way then?

Comment: i would suggest use URL-parameters

Comment: Can you show me an example? Because I'm just a beginner :)

Comment: http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/CodeIgniter-Getting-Parameters-From-GET-P151.html  might help!!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to get this working on a simple HTML website.

The function bellow will check the page URL that the user or visitor is viewing, and compare with the one on the menu item. If they match, it’ll add the `.active` class to that menu item.

Considering your own HTML structure, try the following:

```
// Navigation Markup, let's add an id for easy targeting.

<ul id="nav">
    <li class="dropdown"><a>Home</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a>Articles</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a>About</a></li>
</ul>
```

---

```
// The JS

  jQuery(function() {
    var pgurl = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href
      .lastIndexOf("/")+1);
    jQuery("#nav ul li a").each(function(){
      if(jQuery(this).attr("href") == pgurl || jQuery(this).attr("href") == '' )
        jQuery(this).addClass("active");
    })
  });
```

Note: The function targets the `<a>` elements within the `<ul>` list. In order to target the `<li>` element, slightly change the function.

Answer (score 0):

what worked for me:

```
<nav class="nav">
  <a class="nav-link" href="/">Блог</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="/loler">Об авторе</a>
</nav>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    const regex = /http:\/\/.*\/(.*)\//g;
    const match = regex.exec(window.location.href);
    // iterate over all and find match
    if (match) {
        $(".nav-link").each(function() {
            if ($(this).attr("href").slice(1) == match[1]) {
                $(this).addClass("active");
            }
        });
    }
    // set active first element
    else {
        $(".nav-link:first").addClass("active");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> **The Answer** >>>  add this code directly in your **file.js** in **above**

```
var url = window.location.href;
var tg = url.split('/');

    jQuery('.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link').each(function(){

        url_this = jQuery(this).attr("href");
        var ts = url_this.split('/');


            if(decodeURIComponent(tg[tg.length -2]) === decodeURIComponent(ts[ts.length -1]) ){
                jQuery(this).addClass('active');
                return false;
            }else{
                if(decodeURIComponent(tg[tg.length -2]) === decodeURIComponent(ts[ts.length -2]) ){
                    jQuery(this).addClass('active');
                    return false;
                }
            }


    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar challenge but this worked for me. Considering your structure, i would first advice you give each an id corresponding to the a tags

```
<ul>
<li id="Home" class="dropdown"><a href="Home">Home</a></li>
<li id="Articles" class="dropdown"><a href="Articles">Articles</a></li>
<li id="About" class="dropdown"><a href="About">About</a></li>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var pgurl = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
  var id = "#" + pgurl;
  $(id).attr('class', 'active');



});
```

Note that the nomenclature of the id most tally with that of the hyperlink.
In a case where the href as a ".html" or .php for example:

```
<li id="Articles" class="dropdown"><a href="Articles.php">Articles</a></li>
```

Then use a substring() and indexOf() Method.

```
$(function(){

   var pgurl = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
   var id = "#"+pgurl.substr(0, pgurl.indexOf("."));

      $(id).attr('class','active');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

This should help. Add `.each` too @Ahosan Karim Asik solution.

```
$(document).ready(function(){           
    $(".dropdown  a").each(function(){              
        if($(".dropdown  a").attr("href")==window.location.href){
            $(".dropdown").attr("class","dropdown active");
        }
        else{
            $(".dropdown").attr("class","dropdown");
        }
    });
});
```