# How to set active menu state of div items in jsp file using javascript based on current url?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp

The nav bar looks like this:

[image]

my menu.jsp code which i'm using in all other jsp files to show nav bar menu everywhere:

css code in menu.jsp file

```
    .topnav {
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #e9e9e9;
    }
    
    .topnav a {
      float: left;
      display: block;
      color: black;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 17px;
    }
    
    .topnav a.active {
      background-color: #2196F3;
      color: white;
    }
```

html code in menu.jsp file

```
  <div class="topnav">
  <a class="btn active" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/">Home</a>
  <a class = "btn" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/productList">Product List</a>
  <a class = "btn" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/userInfo">My Account Info</a>
    <a class = "btn" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/login">Login</a>

</div>
```

javascript code:

```
<script>
var btnContainer = document.getElementsByClassName("topnav");

//Get all buttons with class="btn" inside the container
var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("btn");

  
 for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
    btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
     var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
     current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
     this.className += " active";
    });
  </script>
```

I've tried almost all available solution on Stackoverflow and on other sources but none of them worked so far. can anyone tell me how can I resolve this?

Comment: Is this something you looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27877068/jquery-add-class-and-keep-when-page-reload

Comment: @Qontrol it is not working..

Comment: What is not working? What are your errors? Can you be a little more precise?

Comment: @Qontrol I tried the solutions provided there, the end result was none of the menu items got highlighted.. Here is what i did for the first solution of that link: $(document).ready(function(){
    if($(".btn a").attr("href")==window.location.href){
        $(".btn a").attr("class","btn active");
    }
   else{
      $(".btn").attr("class","btn");
     }
});

Comment: Hi did you tried below answer ? does that works for you ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `forEach` to loop through your `a` tags and remove class i.e : `active` and then check if the `href` matches current url then add active class to that `a` tag.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
// var url = window.location.href;
var url = 'https://stacksnippets.net/login' //just for demo..
//loop through `a` remove active class from all if any 
document.querySelectorAll('.topnav a').forEach(function(el) {
  el.classList.remove("active")
});
document.querySelectorAll('.topnav a').forEach(function(el) {
  //check if href matches url ..add active class theere
  if (el.getAttribute('href') === url) {
    el.classList.add("active")
  }
})
```

```css
.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="topnav">
  <a class="btn active" href="https://stacksnippets.net/">Home</a>
  <a class="btn" href="https://stacksnippets.net/productList">Product List</a>
  <a class="btn" href="https://stacksnippets.net/userInfo">My Account Info</a>
  <a class="btn" href="https://stacksnippets.net/login">Login</a>

</div>
```